# Grocery Crud default value after add

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I need to add default images to post, if user do not select an image to upload.
Field to load the image optional.
How can i make it?

**I use this controller.**

```
public function news() {
        $cur_user_id['user_id'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->user_id;
        $this->db->update('news', $cur_user_id);

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_table('news')
                ->display_as('title', 'Заголовок')
                ->display_as('content', 'Текст')
                ->display_as('date', 'Дата')
                ->display_as('urlpict', 'Изображение')
                ->display_as('hide', 'Отображение')
                ->display_as('tags', 'Теги')
                ->display_as('add_new_tags', 'Добавить новые теги')
                ->display_as('menu_id', 'Раздел меню');
        $crud->unset_columns('user_id');
        $crud->required_fields('title', 'content', 'date', 'hide');
        //relation
        $crud->set_relation('menu_id', 'my_menu', 'name');
        $crud->set_relation_n_n('tags', 'tag2art', 'tags', 'art_id', 'tag_id', 'tag');
        //configuration for uploading 
        $this->config->set_item('grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types', 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png');
        $crud->set_field_upload('urlpict', 'assets/uploads/images');
        //callback function

        $crud->callback_after_upload(array($this, 'func_callback_after_upload'));

        $state = $crud->getState();
        $state_info = $crud->getStateInfo();

        if ($state == 'add') {
            $crud->fields('title', 'content', 'date', 'urlpict', 'hide', 'tags', 'add_new_tags', 'menu_id');
            $crud->callback_add_field('add_new_tags', array($this, 'add_field_callback_1'));
        } else {
            $crud->unset_fields('add_new_tags', 'views', 'user_id');
        }
        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->load->view('administrator/news', $output);
    }
```

**It's my callback_function**

```
function func_callback_after_upload($uploader_response, $field_info, $files_to_upload) 
{

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $field_info->upload_path . '/' . $uploader_response[0]->name;
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE; 
    $config['width'] = 175;
    $config['height'] = 175;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
    $this->image_lib->resize(); 
      return true;
}
```

Comment: How can I set the default value for download?

Comment: $crud->set_field_upload('urlpict', 'assets/uploads/images');

Comment: I don't think Codeigniter has such thing but you can check whether a file is selected for the file field or not and accordingly you can do your logic. If file is selected then you can upload selected file else you can upload default file

Comment: Logical solution, and I wanted to do, but not impossible.
`code` $crud->callback_after_update(array($this, 'default_img')); `code`

callback_function
function default_img($post_array, $primary_key) {
        if (!$this->input->post('urlpict')) {
            $default_img = array(
                "id" => $primary_key,
                "urlpict" => "news_default.png"
            );

            $this->db->update('news', $default_img);
            return true;
        }
    }

Comment: but no result I do not get

Answer (score 0):

**Mine solution**
Instead `$crud->callback_after_update(array($this, 'default_img'));`
I used `$crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, 'default_img'));`

**And my controller**

```
function default_img($post_array, $primary_key) {
        if (!$this->input->post('urlpict')) {
            $default_img = array(
                "id" => $primary_key,
                "urlpict" => "news_default.png"
            );

            $this->db->update('news', $default_img, array('id' => $primary_key));
            return true;
        }
    }
```